# group by rollup duplicating results

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

Hi I am trying to use group by rollup to get a grand total for a column but when I do it is duplicating the rows. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Code:

```
WITH TOTS AS
(
select 
swkl.prn_cln_n,
swkl.swkl_bgn_dt,
swkl.swkl_end_dt,
swkl.sec_id,
actbl.*
from actbl
join actblc on actblc.actbl_seq_id = actbl.actbl_seq_id
join swkl on swkl.swkl_id = actblc.swkl_id 
where swkl.prn_cln_n = '242931'
and swkl.stlm_rcd_sta_cd = 'A'
and trunc(swkl.stlm_rcd_mntd_ts) = to_date('03/10/2021','mm/dd/yyyy')   --'14-JUN-2021'
and actblc.actblc_wkfl_pcs_cd = 'COM'
and actblc.stlm_rcd_sta_cd = 'A'
)
,F2 AS
(
SELECT PRN_CLN_N AS CLIENT_NUMBER   
,LINE_TYPE_HM   
,PR_TYP_C   
,SUM(BIIL_A) AS BILL_AMOUNT
FROM TOTS
GROUP BY PRN_CLN_N  
,LINE_TYPE_HM   
,PR_TYP_C
)
SELECT coalesce(CLIENT_NUMBER,'TOTAL') AS CLIENT_NUMBER
,LINE_TYPE_HM
,PR_TYP_C
,SUM(BILL_AMOUNT)  BILL_AMOUNT
FROM F2
group by rollup (CLIENT_NUMBER
,LINE_TYPE_HM
,PR_TYP_C)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong, as far as I can tell.

When using `rollup`, you specify columns in it - `client_number, line_type_hm, pr_typ_c` which is 3 column. `rollup` will produce `3 + 1 = 4` levels of subtotals. Those *subtotals* are visually *identified* by having `NULL` values in rollup columns. In your screenshot,

- 1st level are all "fully populated" lines (those that have all columns with some values, i.e. the 1st line, 3rd, 5th, ...)
- 2nd level are lines whose `pr_typ_c` is `NULL` (2nd line, 4th, 6th, ...)
- 3rd level is the penultimate row (has both `line_type_hm` and `pr_typ_c` empty)
- 4th level is "grand total", the last line with `TOTAL` in `client_number` column

---

I don't have your tables nor data so it is you who might know what to do next because you can **reduce** number of subtotals by performing **partial rollup**. How? For example,

```
group by client_number, rollup(line_type_hm, pr_typ_c)
```

or any other *combination* of rollup columns.

Try it and see what happens.

Comment: It returns the same results.